# Grails 2.4.4 HQL for service tests?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to create a Grails service test that executes an HQL backed service method (executeQuery).  This should now be possible using HibernateTestMixin.   However, I am unable to find or create a working example of this.  This is what I started with:

```
@TestFor(FeatureRelationshipService)
@Mock([FeatureRelationship,Feature,Gene,MRNA])
class FeatureRelationshipServiceSpec extends Specification {
```

this gives me errors about String queries not being supported by GROM (nothing new).

and I changed it to:

```
@TestFor(FeatureRelationshipService)
@TestMixin([HibernateTestMixin,ServiceUnitTestMixin])
@Domain([FeatureRelationship,Feature,Gene,MRNA])
```

or

```
@TestMixin(HibernateTestMixin)
@Domain([FeatureRelationship,Feature,Gene,MRNA])
```

I get the same error:

```
Failure:  parents for feature(org.bbop.apollo.FeatureRelationshipServiceSpec)
|  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with     name 'persistenceInterceptor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
at grails.test.runtime.GrailsApplicationTestPlugin$1.initializeContext(GrailsApplicationTestPlugin.groovy:118)
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that the answer is no.  I rewrote the Query because of this.